# Move cursor focus from one QLabel to another QLabel in Pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have 7 Qlabels  placed in Qgridlayout with 2 rows and 4 columns. I need to change focus from one to another by arrow keys pressing( right, down, left, up). How to get it in pyqt5?

Comment: QLabels don't accept (nor *show*) focus, unless you've set the [`textInteractionFlags`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#textInteractionFlags-prop) property and implement the focus highlight in some way (like using QSS). Please clarify what you're doing and the purpose.

Comment: @musicamante, The options are displayed as a Qlabel and layout in a Grid layout.  user will select their desired option by either mouse click, or navigate it from one label to another by pressing up, down, left or right arrow keys and selecting it by pressing the return or enter key. Number of columns and rows are differ  from layout to layout

Comment: @bala is there something wrong with the approach in my answer?  btw you description sounds more like a button than a label

Comment: @Alexander,  Your Approach to solving the problem is fine and good, But I can't able to move the cursor from up or down. for example, If  My option in third label in row 0,(0,3), if I press down Arrow, then my option will be (1,3).

Comment: @Bala as Alexander pointed out, it seems more like you're going to need buttons instead of labels. Besides, the support shown on their answer can be easily implemented on a basic grid layout, just use `focusWidget()` along with the grid layout [`getItemPosition()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#getItemPosition) and get the "next" widget according to it. Alternatively, use a properly implemented QTableWidget with index widgets (or custom item delegates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable keyboard focus policy on the labels using `label.setFocusPolicy(Qt.TabFocus)`.  Then you would need to register an event filter on each of the labels. And then create an event filter method that listens for arrow key events and changes the focus.

For example:

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.labels = []
        for i in range(2):
            for j in range(4):  # create grid of labels
                label = QLabel(f"Label -> ({i},{j})", self)
                self.layout.addWidget(label,i,j,1,1)
                self.labels.append(label)
                label.installEventFilter(self)   # add event filter
                label.setFocusPolicy(Qt.TabFocus) # set focus policy
        # set the focused widgits background color
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel:focus {background-color: #0f9;}")

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        typ, arrows = event.type(), [Qt.Key_Left, Qt.Key_Right, Qt.Key_Down, Qt.Key_Up]
        # verify the type of event and which key was pressed
        if typ == QEvent.KeyPress and event.key() in arrows:
            key = event.key()
                if key in arrows[:2]:
                    self.focusNextPrevChild(event.key() == arrows[1])
                else:
                    inc = -1 if key == arrows[-1] else 1
                    current = self.focusWidget()
                    pos = self.layout.getItemPosition(self.layout.indexOf(current))
                    widget = self.layout.itemAtPosition(pos[0] + inc,pos[1])
                    widget.widget().setFocus()
                return True
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)
```

I only included left and right in the example... But this should be more than enough to give you the general idea

Comment: how to move by down or up arrow. for example  from (0,3) to (1,3) @Alexander

Comment: @bala  I implemented up down arrow support  hopefully that helps.

Comment: @Alexander, How to get(print) the focused label value?